# Web Api Configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem.

**WebApiConfig**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new
            {
                id = RouteParameter.Optional,
                api = "api",
                namespaces = new string[] { "able.application.api" }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class ContentModelController : ApiController
{
    public ContentModelController()
    {

    }

    [HttpPost, HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int? id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is: When I call get method, I get the following error.

CallUrl: http://localhost:54531/api/ContentModel/get?id=1

Please, help me.. :(

> `<Error>
>   <Message>
>   No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:54531/api/ContentModel/get?id=1'.
>   </Message>
>   <MessageDetail>
>   No type was found that matches the controller named 'ContentModel'.
>   </MessageDetail>
>   </Error>`

Comment: Remove the defaults. They don't seem to apply to anything in the route.

Comment: Sorry..  I get the same error again.

Comment: are you using a local instance of IIS ?

Answer (score 1):

use this template

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { action = "all", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

instead of this

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new
        {
            id = RouteParameter.Optional,
            api = "api",
            namespaces = new string[] { "able.application.api" }
        }
    );
```

in your `WebApiConfig.cs` file.
Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try following Saurabh Srivastava's suggestion and update your API call to:
`http://localhost:54531/api/ContentModel/get/1`

Or you could update the method signature for Get to the following with the original call:
`public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]int? id)`